# Optimising SQL Query with multiple joins, reducing query speed

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

[image]

I'd like some advice on how to optimize the code below. I have attached the relationship of table above, any feedback or direction you could point me to will be appreciated.

The current query seems to be taking quite long to process.

````
SELECT CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVENTTRANSID, CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE, CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEID, CUSTINVOICETRANS.ITEMID, CUSTINVOICETRANS.LINEAMOUNT, CUSTINVOICETRANS.LINEAMOUNTTAX, CUSTINVOICETRANS.ORIGSALESID, CUSTINVOICETRANS.QTY, CUSTINVOICETRANS.SUMLINEDISC, CUSTINVOICEJOUR.CUSTGROUP, CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEACCOUNT, CUSTINVOICEJOUR.SALESID, SALESTABLE.VCORDERMODE, SALESTABLE.VCORDERRT, VCSALESTABLEINFO.RCVDATE, VCSALESTABLEINFO.SHPCSTMCD, VCSALESTABLEINFO.VCORIGINALINVOICEDATE, SALESLINE.DATAAREADID, SALESLINE.INVENTTRANSID, VCSALESLINEINFO.RLLINEID

FROM CUSTINVOICETRANS

INNER JOIN CUSTINVOICEJOUR
ON CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEID = CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID
AND CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE = CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEDATE
AND CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())

INNER JOIN SALESTABLE
ON CUSTINVOICETRANS.ORIGSALESID = SALESTABLE.SALESID
AND CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())

INNER JOIN VCSALESTABLEINFO
ON CUSTINVOICETRANS.ORIGSALESID = VCSALESTABLEINFO.SALESID
AND CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())

INNER JOIN SALESLINE
ON CUSTINVOICETRANS.ORIGSALESID = SALESLINE.SALESID
AND CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())

INNER JOIN VCSALESLINEINFO
ON SALESLINE.INVENTTRANSID = VCSALESLINEINFO.INVENTTRANSID```
````

Comment: The first thing to improve a query is to remove duplicate commands. Remove these lines (`CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())`) and put them in the `WHERE` .
In the next step, check if an index has been created on the fields that participate in the join?

Comment: Based on the syntax, this appears to be SQL Server, *not* MySQL. Please don't use conflicting tags, it can make it harder to help you.

Comment: Do you have an index on `custinvoicetrans.invoicedate`? In the actual execution plan, what is the operation against the `custinvoicetrans` table, (table scan? Index seek?), what is the estimated number of rows, and what is the actual number of rows returned?

Comment: Barest minimum to diagnose a SQL performance problem is: tables and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. It's not answerable otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte` to filter first your **customer invoice transactions** before joining other tables.

```
WITH cte as
    (
        SELECT INVENTTRANSID, INVOICEDATE, INVOICEID
            , ITEMID, LINEAMOUNT, LINEAMOUNTTAX
            , ORIGSALESID, QTY, SUMLINEDISC  
        FROM CUSTINVOICETRANS WHERE INVOICEDATE>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())
    )
SELECT t1.*, t2.CUSTGROUP, t2.INVOICEACCOUNT, t2.SALESID
    , t3.VCORDERMODE, t3.VCORDERRT
    , t4.RCVDATE, t4.SHPCSTMCD, t4.VCORIGINALINVOICEDATE
    , t5.DATAAREADID, t5.INVENTTRANSID
    , t6.RLLINEID
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN CUSTINVOICEJOUR t2 on t2.INVOICEID = t1.INVOICEID and t1.INVOICEDATE = t2.INVOICEDATE
INNER JOIN SALESTABLE t3 on t3.SALESID = t1.ORIGSALESID  
INNER JOIN VCSALESTABLEINFO t4 on t4.SALESID = t1.ORIGSALESID
INNER JOIN SALESLINE t5 on t5.SALESID = t1.ORIGSALESID
INNER JOIN VCSALESLINEINFO t6 on t6.INVENTTRANSID = t5.INVENTTRANSID
```

Comment: Why should it be faster? This filter will be moved to the table access by an optimizer in almost any modern database, and this table is accessed only once

Comment: @astentx No one can actually know if this approach will be an improvement. Given the names that start with "v", there are likely views referenced whose complexity we cannot know. As complexity of the query increases, the optimizer has more work to do and might choose a less efficient plan. Sometimes rearranging the query can help guide the optimizer to a better plan.

Comment: @SMor Then the prerequisite is an *actual* query plan. Without it any rearrangement is a guess which may or may not improve the query, so doen't add much value to the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the first INNER JOIN outcome to a dataframe / temp table t1. 
Join the same with second INNER Join dataset. 
pull the data into another temp  table / data frame. 
Drop the temp table t1 at the end.  
Follow the step for for subsequesnt joins.

Regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).